# Customising ActiveAdmin CSV output by admin level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activeadmin

I would like to limit the columns of the CSV download in a similar manner in which I limit the items of the index area.

For my index I have:

```
index do
    column "Name" do |purchase|
      purchase.user.full_name
    end
    if current_admin_user.superuser?
      column "User" do |purchase|
          link_to purchase.user.email, admin_user_path(purchase.user)
      end
    end
end
```

in which only high-level admins can view the user's email addresses.

if I do the same for CSV, AA throws an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_admin_user'
```

I can do the current_admin_user check within the function without an error:

```
column "User Name" do |purchase|
  if current_admin_user.superuser?
    purchase.user.full_name.gsub(',','')
  end
end
```

but this is a little sloppy as it leaves me with dead columns for lesser admin users.

Any one got a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
index do
  column "Name" do |purchase|
    purchase.user.full_name
  end
  column "User", :if => proc{ current_admin_user.superuser? } do |purchase|
      link_to purchase.user.email, admin_user_path(purchase.user)
  end
  end
end
```